# Select from multi access tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Try to get result of this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       invoices.invoice_id,
       invoices.customer,
       invoices.total,
       SUM(pay_amount) AS paid
FROM invoices,
     invoice_payment
WHERE invoices.invoice_id = invoice_payment.invoice_id
      AND invoices.type = 'client'
      AND invoice_payment.pay_type <> 'postpaid'
      AND format(invoices.create_date, "dd/mm/yyyy") BETWEEN '01/11/2017' AND '14/11/2017';
```

I got

> "Your query does not include the specific expression 'invoice_id' as
>   part of an aggregate function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` when you are aggregating data, e.g. count, sum etc

Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       invoices.invoice_id,
       invoices.customer,
       invoices.total,
       SUM(pay_amount) AS paid
FROM invoices,
     invoice_payment
WHERE invoices.invoice_id = invoice_payment.invoice_id
      AND invoices.type = 'client'
      AND invoice_payment.pay_type <> 'postpaid'
      AND format(invoices.create_date, "dd/mm/yyyy") BETWEEN '01/11/2017' AND '14/11/2017'
GROUP BY invoices.invoice_id,
         invoices.customer,
         invoices.total;
```

The Access docs for `GROUP BY` are [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/GROUP-BY-Clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0)

Also try to avoid the old style joins, they are nasty and outdated. This would be much better:

```
FROM invoices
INNER JOIN invoice_payment ON invoices.invoice_id = invoice_payment.invoice_id
```

Comment: I don't really know what that means.... If you add some sample data then it will make more sense. What are you expecting it to show?